# How to increment MongoDB id sequence from a specific number in Spring Boot?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, java-8, sequence

Here is my code it increments from 1. but I want to start the id number from 100 and increment 1, for example 100, 101, 102, 103.

```java
public int generateSeq(String seqname) {
    Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(seqName));
    Update update = new Update().inc("seq", 1);
    Dbseq counter = mongoOperations.findAndModify(query, update, options().returnNew(true).upsert(true), DbSeq.class);
    return !Objects.isNull(counter) ? counter.getSeq() : 1;
}
```

I changed the number from 1 in `inc` function to 100 instead of 100, 101,102 etc; it prints 100,200,300. Can you let me know what is mossing here?

Comment: `inc` update operator _increments_ the existing field value by a given number. If you provide the number as 100, the value will be added to the existing value. If you provide 1, that will be added to the existing value. That is the expected behaviour. To start the numbers from 100, first you need to have 100 in the existing value and then start incrementing it by 1.

Comment: the question is how to add and where to add the existing number 100 in the code so that inc function will take it and add 1 to it

Comment: In general, you add a document with fields and values using one of the available _insert_ methods on a collection. So, it is possible for including the field during the insert operation.

Comment: i didnt get u. can u update the code what you are saying